# Java switch between 3 images

Tags: java, android

How should I do if i want to switch images depending of the position.

I got a for loop, going from 0 to any number, and the idea its that the image will switch depending of the value,

eg.

```
    on position 0, it should display image 'A'
    on position 1, it should display image 'B'
    on position 2, it should display image 'C'
    on position 3, it should display image 'A' again
    on position 4, it should display image 'B' again
```

and so on, always switching in order between those 3 images

Thanks in advance

Comment: Let me introduce you a fantastic operator - modulus http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supose your images are on drawble folder and you will put them on some view on your activity.

```
int imagesRid = {R.id.imageA, R.id.imageB, R.id.imageC}
for(int i=0;i<anyNo;i++)
{
     view.setBrackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(imagesRid[i%imagesRid.lenght]))    

}
```

}

Comment: thanks a lot, i liked your answer, was the best one for what i needed

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=1;
for(int i=0;i<anyNo;i++)
{
    switch(count)
     {
           case 1:
               //display A
                break; 
           case 2:
              //display B
               break; 

           case 3:
              //display C
              break; 


    }
      count++;

     if(count>3)
     count=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use module arithmetic. For better understanding you can see how circular queue has been implemented

```
0%3=0
1%3=1
2%3=2
3%3=0
4%3=1
5%3=5
6%3=0
```

So you can see that number will be in range of 0-2 for module 3, 0-3 for module 4